# How to merge rows in MS access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having a table with records like this in MS Access:

```
ID  field2  field3  field4  field5
1   345       asr
2             ase     567    788
3   456       ghy
4             jki     568    899
5   235       yui
6             hju     456    456
```

I want to merge it to get a table like this:

```
ID      field2  field3  field4  field5
1           345 asrase     567    788
3           456 ghyjki     568    899
5           235 yuihju     456    456
```

Is this possible with queries?

Comment: We can probably whip up someting.  First, we need to agree on the rules that dictate that two (or more?) rows will contribute to the same row in the resulting table.  1) is the belonging to same table established by the lack of a field2 value _and_ ID directly following the last record with a field2 value.  2) what happens if we have more than one value for the field4 or field5 (say if we had 3 rows total for input two of which with field4 values) ?

Comment: as of now we can safely assume the fields 4 and 5 will have one value only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rows continue like the example, this query would do:

```
select a.id, 
    a.field2, 
    a.field3 + Iif(IsNull(b.field3),'',b.field3), 
    b.field4, 
    b.field5
from table1 a
left join table1 b on b.id = a.id + 1
where a.field2 is not null
```

It joins the table on itself, looking for the next row.  It combines both rows to produce the desired result.

Comment: Assuming that the table i have given above itself is a result of a query from a larger table where the records are not necessarily like this. Will this as a sub query work to update in the original table.

Comment: You could use this query as a "create new table" query.

Comment: one more doubt is can we directly add like this a.field3+b.field3

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably can. Judging from your example rows, you want each "even" and "odd" row to merge together in a well-defined way.

With this kind of problem, if you don't know the way, I'd start using the query editor to play around. For example, can you create a query that calculates a pseudo-id of 1/2 th actual ID? I think you can, and that will let you get a common ID to relate the 2 fields with.

But there are other ways to relate the two fields. You could merge the table with itself, choosing the first version as those with a non-NULL field 4 (or 5), and the second where the ID is the same as the ID of the first -1.

If you use the 1/2 ID ID method I proposed first, the easy thing to do is create 1 query to get the "even" and another to get the "odd" rows. Then you simply merge the two queries in a third one.

Once you have a solution, you can muck around with it, and try other things.

I'd start by playing in the query editor, and then look at the SQL when you're done.

PS: I'm sure I could code your answer for you, but what fun would you have then? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I went with a slightly different approach to Andomar and used the mod function to return even rows.

```
SELECT a.id, a.field2, a.field3 + IIF(b.field3 IS NULL,'', b.field3), 
       b.field4, b.field5
  FROM Table1 AS a
       INNER JOIN Table1 AS b 
          ON a.ID = b.ID + 1
 WHERE Table1_1.ID MOD 2 = 0;
```

Comment: In both cases I am getting an error that wrong number of arguments used for the function Isnull(b.field3,''). I am not sure what is wromg here. Isnull can be used in Ms Access right?

Comment: Ah right, Access ISNULL takes only 1 parameter.  Try this:  Iif(IsNull(b.field3),'',b.field3)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the answers here are robust, given that it depends on the ID fields being consecutive, and that even if it *is* consecutive, that it is the *right* value in the next consecutive record.

I would like to know more about the data in Field3, i.e., whether or not it is meaningful.

Comment: the first one worked for me. the data in field 3 is a description of a product basically